# Problems handling response.status in auth.authResponseChange event

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-authentication, xfbml

I want to create a login system that can also use FB's login. So I've setup the FB object and SDK in my page and then subscribed to the `auth.authResponseChange` event and added an anonymous function to do stuff if I'm logged, not logged or not authorized.

When I'm logged it works properly. When I'm not logged or not authorized, it does nothing. I think it just doesn't enter into the anonymous function either, because I've put a console.log() before the `if` and it does nothing.

Here's my code:

```
// Facebook stuff
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'my id blabla', // App ID
    channelUrl : 'my channel.html bla bla', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response)
  {
    console.log("Running function");

    if(response.status === "connected")
    {
        console.log("Connected and authorized");
    }
    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized')
    {
        console.log("Not authorized");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Not connected");
    }
  });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d)
{
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but for what it's worth if you subscribe to the event 'auth.statusChange' instead of 'authResponseChange' you can know if he is 'connected' to facebook and authorized your app or if he's connected to fb but not authorized.

Also if you use the FB.getLoginStatus, which facebook advise not to, you can know in what of the three states (connected, not_autorized or not_connected) the user is in.